# Incorrect Particle colors in viewport

Tags: 3d-view, particles, color

I can't see the real colors of the particles in the viewport.

[image: viewport]

But I can see the real colors of the particles after rendering. The colors are the same in material and render preview mode.

[image: render results]

I think I have to configure some settings to see the real colors but I have no idea how to do it. I google it but I cannot find anything.

Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: I figured it myself. thank you for your concerning!!

Comment: awesome! sorry was busy. can u post the answer?

Comment: it was very simple. on particle system. I put velocity option instead of materials on Viewport display color in particle properties.